# how to install cloud9 IDE on ubuntu server

Tags: python, ubuntu, web, editor, hosted

I have a development server which runs mostly python-based apps. 
I like the interface of tools like cloud9, but since I have a server I'd rather have something similar on my own server. This is what I mean by "self-hosting". I only need to edit local files (ie, files on that server).

The server is running Ubuntu server 12.04. 
cloud9 is apparently available for self-hosting, but I have never used node.js and I don't want to learn about it if possible. I know that cloud 9 also offer ssh integration with other servers, but I'm hoping to find a package I can easily install on Ubuntu and easily configure.

There is a similar question on stackoverflow but from 2009.

Comment: As primarily opinion-soliciting questions are downvoted, deleted from SO, I suggest you rename it to something like "how to install Cloud9 IDE on Ubuntu"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Cloud9's git repository and instructions have changed since the other answer was posted. See https://github.com/c9/core/ for more information. The following instructions seem to work for me on a vanilla Ubuntu 14.04.

1. [Install Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) if you haven't already:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential
   sudo apt-get install git
   ```
2. [Install node.js](http://nodejs.org/) if you don't already have a recent version installed:

   ```
   # Install node.js
   wget -O  ~/node-v0.10.33-linux-x64.tar.gz http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.33/node-v0.10.33-linux-x64.tar.gz
   tar -zxf ~/node-v0.10.33-linux-x64.tar.gz
   rm       ~/node-v0.10.33-linux-x64.tar.gz
   echo 'export PATH=$PATH:~/node-v0.10.33-linux-x64/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```
3. Download and setup Cloud9:

   ```
   # Setup and start Cloud9 server
   # (You can get a zip file instead of using git)
   git clone https://github.com/c9/core.git c9sdk
   c9sdk/scripts/install-sdk.sh
   ```
4. After the server starts successfully, you can stop it with `Ctrl-C`. Then you can start it with a different workspace:

   ```
   node c9sdk/server.js -w ~/my_workspace/
   ```
5. Visit http://localhost:8181 to see the Cloud9 IDE in your browser.

If you don't like the self-hosted Cloud9 web-IDE, you can try [Orion](http://eclipse.org/orion/), [Codiad](http://codiad.com/), or [Codebox](https://github.com/CodeboxIDE/codebox).

Comment: Missed a step on vanilla Ubuntu 14.04: sudo apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential

Comment: This: `node c9sdk/server.js -w ~/my_workspace/` helped.

Comment: if using Ubuntu 16.04 you also need to run `apt-get install python2.7` as v3 is included by default

Comment: How is this working for you now? I'm curious if port 8181 is open to anybody, or if it comes bundled with some login management? Thanks for listing some alternatives too!

Comment: If you specify an IP with `--listen` it asks you to turn on the authorization parameter. Very helpful!

Answer (score 7):

Getting Cloud9 IDE installed on your own server is not as hard as you may think.

It is basically these steps:

1. [Install node.js](https://askubuntu.com/a/49391/93577)
2. [Clone Cloud9's Git repository to your server and install](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/#installation-and-usage)
3. Run a command in the terminal to start the Cloud9 app:

`bin/cloud9.sh -w ~/git/myproject -l 0.0.0.0`

You can then access your Cloud9 app at `http://yourserveraddress:3131` (3131 being the default port it will serve on.

As requested, you will not have learned much about node.js in the process ;)

Comment: thanks. I had some fun getting a compatible version of node.js on ubuntu LTS, but after that it was easy.

Comment: welcome. it is a great setup and though I have great bandwidth in office now, I'm often using mobile data on the road and having this setup remote, along with some tmux sessions or a Gate One setup for web based terminal, it's really quite powerful for thin client computing. ps. an upvote on the accepted answer will give an angel her wings ;)