# How can I deploy c9 on google compute engine?

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-platform, cloud9-ide

Basically going off of this post: [how to install cloud9 IDE on ubuntu server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929093/how-to-install-cloud9-ide-on-ubuntu-server), I've tried repeatedly to launch a self-hosted instance of cloud9 a cloud compute VM to no avail.

Not sure what I'm missing - I've followed all the steps outlined there, past and present, and tried multiple other guides. If there is anyone here who can perhaps provide more current directions that'd be great..

I don't have the rep to comment on the original post, else I would!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please write in to support@c9.io with the problems you're encountering. Thanks!

Comment: Have you made sure that you've opened the right network ports? By default it appears that the port is 3131 which is not exposed by default in GCE.  You'll need to open up a port using [firewalls in GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking?hl=en#addingafirewall) or through the web interface.

Answer (score 1):

Huge thanks to Terry - the issue was the blocked port. **Connecting through IP:3131 after opening it on the network fixed the issue.**

Thanks Mutahhir also, but we've saved you all a ticket!